# How to boot from USB in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, bios, usb-flash-drive

I'm trying to install Ubuntu along with Windows 8. I have copied the Ubuntu 64bit ISO in a USB Pendrive [aka *USB Flash Drive*] and now I'm trying to boot from there. In the BIOS, I select *First Boot Device* where I have some options:

- Hard disk
- CDROM
- ZIP
- USB-FDD
- USB-ZIP
- USB-CDROOM
- USB-HDD

I have tried the four USB options and no one work. It keeps booting from my Hard Disk so Windows 8 starts. As the *Second boot device* I have selected the *Hard disk* option.

So how can I properly boot from my USB pendrive where I have the Ubuntu ISO?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1 absolutely nothing to do with windows 8. Don't you know the BIOS is before windows. Try taking the hard disks out And you'll see it still isn't booting. see what joe said. And crazy how you said you can't boot from USB yet  you only tested one USB. That's not exactly a good way to make such a diagnosis is it. You obviously don't boot from usb in windows that is just nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with how you put the ISO on the USB.
Have you tried following the instructions the Ubuntu Team released [HERE](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)?

After following the instructions linked to in the above paragraph, your USB should boot with either the "USB-HDD" or the "USB-ZIP" boot option.

If that still doesn't work, your USB might be faulty, or your computer might not support USB booting.

Comment: Yes, that's what the problem. I found that solution before you post this, but I'll mark as accepted because of your help! And others that probably will have the same trouble in the future will know that this is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found the solution by accident.

Already tired of restarting again and again without burning took the USB as boot, I chose the option `Hard disk` and only then a choice appeared to me between the `HDD` and `USB`.

My motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-P55-USB3.